# With a VS Solution how can I setup a group of source files using matching settings, and specific settings for files that need special treatment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, precompiled-headers

The question is how can I setup a group of source files using matching settings, and specific settings for files that need special treatment?

My question came about because of a build issue which I have now figured out

Comment: This is not how you do a self answer Q&A.  Your question needs to contain an actual question that anyone can answer.  As is there is no question in your question body.

Comment: I'm not sure how re-stating the question again in the body adds any information.  I have re-titled it with a more specific question,

Comment: It is just how the site works. It is a Q&A site, following a very strict model. The "question" part has to ask a question, the "answer" part has to contain the answer. It doesn't matter if you are self-answering, you still need to follow the same model as you would for any other question. This is not a blog, or a message board, or something like that where you can just free-form.

Answer (score -1):

The following is roughly how that project system seems to work.

Please correct any misconceptions.

#### 1.  There are three types of settings

- i) Property Page Settings (these can be inherited)
- ii) Project Settings
- iii) File Settings

  Project settings affect all source files that do not have a file setting

  Project settings are specific to a configuration

  When examining a file setting (a file node rather than a project node is selected) items showing in Bold are settings set at file level
  If the setting is not bold then it is a File Setting

  Within the project settings (the project node is selected) any items showing as bold are project settings, any showing as not bold are inherited from a property sheet

#### 2.  Any file that doesn't have a file level setting uses the project settings

#### 3.  To set a project setting make sure to click the project node

#### 4. To set a file setting click on the file that you want the setting to affect

#### 5. If the tool type you need to modify is not showing as available under project settings, briefly select a file for which that tool is valid and then re-click the project node

A good example of doing this is when you want to use pre-compiled headers.  In this instance the majority of files need to consume the pre-compiled header and so you would set `Use \Yu` under C/C++->Precompiled Headers:Precompiled Header

Then under `stdafx.cpp` you would make it a file level setting (clicking on stdafx.cpp) and select `Create \Yc` under C/C++->Precompiled Headers:Precompiled Header

Your project might also contain .C files that have been generated by Midl, and so for those files you would at file level select `Not Using Precompiled Headers` under C/C++->Precompiled Headers:Precompiled Header

I am now trying to get to the root of what is causing MSBuild Error MSB8028 in one of my projects.

`However the test project I created to research the problem does not seem to be obeying the rules I set out above.  Each of the .cpp files in the project are ignoring the project setting for Precompiled Headers, but they are showing as non-bold`

The above statement is false, but it has led me to the golden rule!

**Make sure 'Configuration' contains the word 'Active'**

Of course you can ignore this rule, but make sure to keep it in your mind to avoid the possibility that you have not created a setting within the wrong configuration, which will explain why the behaviour you were expecting is not actually what you are getting